# Displaying the content dynamically from the dynamic id of the button using jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

**Scenario:**

I have a bit tricky case here:

Upon cicking the button inside the first div block (I have named it as DIV Block A for readability), I want to display the channels which is inside the second DIV Block 
(I have named it as DIV Block B for readability).

The id of button from DIV Block A is:

```
id="sub_category_dc_button_<?=$category['category_id'];?>"
```

Upon clicking this button, the content inside the DIV Block B should be displayed.

**Attempt 1:**

For this, I have followed this approach:

```
$(".sub_dc_channels").on("click", function(){ 
    $($(this).attr("data-target")).show(); 
  });
```

**Here is my DIV Block A:**

```
<div class="sub_cat_buttons channel" id="dc_subcategory_button_tab">
       <div class="sub_dc_channels" id="sub_dc_button"> 
           <?php foreach ($output as $category) {                                                                       
               <button type="button" data-toggle="collapse" 
                  id="sub_category_dc_button_<?=$category['category_id'];?>"      
                  class="btn btn-primary sub_digitalchannel_button"
                  data-target="#Category_<?= $category['category_id'];?>">                                                   
                  <?= $category['category_title']?> 
               </button>                                                          
        </div> 
    </div>
```

**Here is my DIV Block B:**

```
<?php  foreach ($output as $category) {?>                  
     <div class="channel" id="Category_<?= $category['category_id'];?>"> 
    <div id="subchannel_list_tab"> 
           <?php  foreach ($output as $category) {?>  
           <?php foreach ($category['channels'] as $channels) { ?>                                                                                                                                          
         <img src="<?= $channels['channel_logo']; ?>" 
         alt="<?= $channels['channel_name']; ?>"
         title="<?= $channels['channel_name']; ?>"
         style="width: 100px; height: 60px;" />                                
       <?php } ?>
       <?php } ?> 
    </div>                          
     </div>
 <?php } ?>
```

**Attempt 2:**

I have also used this approach with the same DIV Blocks but it fails too.

```
$('div[id^="Category_"]').click(function() {  
    $(".channel").hide();   
    $("#subchannel_list_tab").show();
});
```

**Issue Faced:**

**When I clicked the button from DIV Block A then it targets the contents inside the DIV Block B but the contents inside the DIV Block B are not shown.**

**What am I missing here? Or am I following the wrong approach?
Suggestions are highly appreciated.**

Comment: Your click event is defined on `.sub_dc_channels`, which is the surrounding div, whereas your `data-target` is on the `<button>`s. You probably want to bind your click event to these buttons instead.

Answer (score 1):

your click is going to be triggered in the div and not in the button, it is likely that this is the problem.

Here's a dummy example of what I think you're up to.

```js
$('.showDiv').click( function () {
   let div = $(this).attr('data-target');
   $(`#${div}`).show();
});
```

```css
#divB {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="divA">
  <button class="showDiv" data-target="divB">show div</button>
</div>
<div id="divB">
  info divB
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to show dynamic data as per id of button click.You missed a target button class in selector.your issue is solved.

```
$(document).on("click",".sub_dc_channels .sub_digitalchannel_button",function(){ 
    alert();
    $($(this).attr("data-target")).show(); 
});
```

for reference you can [click here](https://jsfiddle.net/nz156gmr/4/).

Comment: Thank you so much for your feedback. The button got clicked and it shows some content as well. Since the button from DIV Block A is generated dynamically as it is bind with <?=$category['category_id'];?> as you can see above. That means every button has different id and every button is pointing to the different content to show as seen in DIV Block B. But when any button is clicked then it is showing same content. What correction do I need here? Thanks again!

Comment: in my example if you click on DIV BLOCK A it shows content 1 and click on DIV BLOCK B it shows content 2,so it's working perfect.so make sure your data -target would be same as the ID of your block which you want to display.check it properly.